# Replace string elements in a list with elements in tuples by considering the order information

Tags: python

Trying to replace `My_list` elements with the elements of `Replace` tuples (Replace element[0] -> Replace element[1]), but considering the order information. (As you can see, `My_list` has 4 "a"s the same as `Replace` has 4 "a"s)

```
My_list = ["a","ab","ab","c","ad"]
Replace = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("a","d"),("a","e")]
```

To do so, it is necessary to take into account the order between two like:

> **1**."a" , **2**."ab", **3**."ab", 4."c", **5**."ad"
>
> **1**.("a","b"), **2**.("a","c"), **3**.("a","d"), **5**.("a","e")

However, all I can do, for now, is just replace all of them by the last elements of given tuples like this:

```
results = []
for item in My_list:
    for elements in Replace:
        result = re.sub(elements[0],elements[1],item)
    results.append(result)
print(results)

['e', 'eb', 'eb', 'c', 'ed']
```

What I actually want to result in with the two is:

```
["b","cb","db","c","ed"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate and replace if only available else pick the next element:

```
My_list = ["a","ab","ab","c","ad"]
Replace = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("a","d"),("a","e")]

j = 0
for i in range(len(My_list)):
    r = Replace[j]
    if r[0] in My_list[i]:
        My_list[i] = My_list[i].replace(r[0], r[1])
        j += 1        
    
print(My_list)
```

.. which prints:

```
['b', 'cb', 'db', 'c', 'ed']
```

---

I would suggest to use *`snake_case`* for variable and function names.

Answer (score 2):

```py
My_list = ["a","ab","ab","c","ad"]
Replace = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("a","d"),("a","e")]

i = 0
for ind, item in enumerate(My_list):
    if Replace[i][0] in item:
        My_list[ind] = item.replace(Replace[i][0], Replace[i][1])
        i += 1

print(My_list)
```

output:

```
['b', 'cb', 'db', 'c', 'ed']
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you want. It's not optimized and doesn't use regular expressions but you can see the logic. The main change is that you do not need two loops for the exchange of items in My_list with the 2nd tuple element in Replace.

```
My_list = ["a","ab","ab","c","ad"]
Replace = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("a","d"),("a","e")]

results = []
count = 0
for item in My_list:
    if item[0] == Replace[count][0]:
        if (len(item) == 1):
            results.append(Replace[count][1])
            count += 1
        elif (len(item) == 2):
            results.append(Replace[count][1] + item[1])
            count += 1
    else:
        results.append(item)  
print(results)
#  ["b","cb","db","c","ed"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner, you can try following but forgive my mistakes, thank you.

```
my_list = ("".join(["a","ab","ab","c","ad"])).split()
replace = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("a","d"),("a","e")]

#eliminate a from my list
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != "a",my_list[0]))

#make a list from replace
list1 = [k for j, k in replace]

#zipping two list
result1 = list(zip(new_list,list1))

#final result in a tuple
final_result = [j if j == k else (j, k) for j, k in result1]
print(final_result)

#you can unpack final tuple if you want it to be a string
```